# Name of sorting algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I'm trying to figure out the name of a sorting algorithm (or just a method?) that sorts via 3 values.

We start off with 3 values and the array should sort based on the id of the object, position and then the date it was set to that position, allowing both date and position to be the same. Please excuse my horrible explanation. I will give an example.

we have 6 positions, without any edits the array would look something like this

```
{id:1,pos:0,date:0}
{id:2,pos:0,date:0}
{id:3,pos:0,date:0}
{id:4,pos:0,date:0}
{id:5,pos:0,date:0}
{id:6,pos:0,date:0}
```

if I was to move the first object to the second position, it would return this order

```
{id:2,pos:0,date:0}
{id:1,pos:2,date:1}
{id:3,pos:0,date:0}
{id:4,pos:0,date:0}
{id:5,pos:0,date:0}
{id:6,pos:0,date:0}
```

However if we where to then move the third object into the second position

```
{id:2,pos:0,date:0}
{id:3,pos:2,date:2}
{id:1,pos:2,date:1}
{id:4,pos:0,date:0}
{id:5,pos:0,date:0}
{id:6,pos:0,date:0}
```

Note the pos does not change but is ordered before positions of the same number based on the higher date value.

We now move the 4th object into position 1

```
{id:4,pos:1,date:3}
{id:2,pos:0,date:0}
{id:3,pos:2,date:2}
{id:1,pos:2,date:1}
{id:5,pos:0,date:0}
{id:6,pos:0,date:0}
```

note id 2 takes the position of number 2 even though pos and date are still 0 because the id is less than the id behind it

We now move id 6 to position 2

```
{id:4,pos:1,date:3}
{id:6,pos:2,date:4}
{id:2,pos:0,date:0}
{id:3,pos:2,date:2}
{id:1,pos:2,date:1}
{id:5,pos:0,date:0}
```

id 5 to position 4

```
{id:4,pos:1,date:3}
{id:6,pos:2,date:4}
{id:2,pos:0,date:0}
{id:5,pos:4,date:5}
{id:3,pos:2,date:2}
{id:1,pos:2,date:1}
```

And finally id 2 to position 6

```
{id:4,pos:1,date:3}
{id:6,pos:2,date:4}
{id:5,pos:4,date:5}
{id:3,pos:2,date:2}
{id:1,pos:2,date:1}
{id:2,pos:6,date:6}
```

I hope my examples aid any response given, I know this is not a question of much quality and if answered I will do my best to edit the question as best I can.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're actually doing here, you're just moving things into different places? We have no idea what the process is behind deciding which items move and where they move to, so this is almost impossible to answer like this.

Comment: I am literally just moving things into other positions via an interface, but I'm trying to understand how I could achieve this output given the data I have to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, because your final order doesn't look "sorted", lexicographical sort? See [Lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).

Comment: Am currently running a test on my data set, will update soon. Thanks for your entry!

Comment: Sadly I was unable to replicate my desired effect using the Lexicographical order, much appreciate the answer, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The movement of objects is similar to insertion sort, where an entire sub-array is shifted in order to insert an object. The date indicates the order of operations that were performed, and the position indicates where the object was moved to, but there's no field for where an object was moved from. There's enough information to reproduce the sequence by starting with the initial ordering and following the moves according to the date. I don't know if the sequence can be followed in reverse with the given information.

The original ordering can be restored using any sort algorithm using the id field.

Answer (score 0):

I was unfortunately unable to find the name of the 'sort'(?) however, I was able to achieve the effect I was aiming for using the code bellow.

(If I missed something entirely let me know I'll change it and credit you)

PHP Implementation.

```
$data = '[
    {"id":"1","pos":"1","date":"0"},
    {"id":"2","pos":"5","date":"0"},
    {"id":"3","pos":"4","date":"0"},
    {"id":"4","pos":"3","date":"0"},
    {"id":"5","pos":"4","date":"1"},
    {"id":"6","pos":"2","date":"0"}
]'; //simulated data set

$arr = json_decode($data,true);
$final_arr = $arr;

$tmp_array = array();
$actions = array();

for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($arr); $i++) {
    $num = $i+1;
    $tmp = array();
    for ($o=0; $o < sizeof($arr); $o++) {
        if($arr[$o]['pos'] == 0)continue;

        if($arr[$o]['pos'] == $num){
            array_push($tmp,$arr[$o]);
        }
    }
    if($tmp){
        usort($tmp,function($a,$b){
            return $a['date'] > $b['date'];
        });

        for ($o=0; $o < sizeof($tmp); $o++) {
            array_push($tmp_array,$tmp[$o]);
        }
    }
}
for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($tmp_array); $i++) {
    for ($o=0; $o < sizeof($arr); $o++) {
        if($final_arr[$o]['id'] == $tmp_array[$i]['id']){
            array_splice($final_arr, $tmp_array[$i]['pos']-1, 0, array_splice($final_arr, $o, 1));
        }
    }
}

$output = json_encode($final_arr,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
printf($output);
```

Result:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "pos": "1",
        "date": "0"
    },
    {
        "id": "6",
        "pos": "2",
        "date": "0"
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "pos": "3",
        "date": "0"
    },
    {
        "id": "5",
        "pos": "4",
        "date": "1"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "pos": "5",
        "date": "0"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "pos": "4",
        "date": "0"
    }
]
```